# Convergence proof for $\sqrt{a_n}$ → $\sqrt{a}$ when $a_n \to a$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

> Suppose that $a_n \geq 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$ and $a_n \to a$, where $a \in \mathbb R$. Prove $\sqrt{a_n} \to \sqrt{a}$.

## My attempt

WTS: $\exists a \in \mathbb R, \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N > 0$, such that for all $n \in \mathbb N$, if $n > N$, then $|a_n - a| < \epsilon$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary.

Choose $ N $ such that $|a_n - a| < \epsilon$.

Suppose $n > N$, then

$|\sqrt{a_n} - \sqrt{a}| 
= |a_n - a | < \epsilon$

I squared both sides. This part I'm iffy about and don't think it's right.

Comment: The idea of bounding $|\sqrt{a_n}-\sqrt{a}|$ by $|a_n-a|$ is a very brilliant one. You just need to link these two values together. These are not equal and are neither proportional, but they are different by a multiplicative factor that can be bounded using the fact that the sequence has a limit. 

I think you can figure it out on your own.

Comment: "Squaring both sides" isn't adequate here, as $|\sqrt a_n-\sqrt a|^2=|a_n+a-2\sqrt{a_na}|\neq|a_n-a|$. As a hint for the correct algebreaic approach, consider the factoring $a_n-a=(\sqrt a_n-\sqrt a)(\sqrt a_n+\sqrt a)$.

Comment: It's also not true that $|\sqrt{a_n}-a|\leq|a_n-a|$ in all cases.

Comment: I suggest divide two cases: $a = 0$ and $a > 0$ then for the latter case use $\sqrt{a_n} - \sqrt{a} = \frac{a_n - a}{\sqrt{a_n} + \sqrt{a}}$.

Comment: I like your way @Zhanxiong , FOR a = 0, the sequence would be {0,0,0,0,0...} , for a > 0, can I let $$|a_n - a| < (\sqrt{R}+\sqrt{a}) \epsilon \text{ where } R := sup(|a_n|)$$ ?

Comment: For $ a = 0 $ there are other possibilities. For example you can have $ a _ n = \frac 1 n $.

Comment: isnt that a_n tho? $|a_n - 0 | < \epsilon$ is what i have to prove i think?

Comment: @user349557 I will write an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment, there are two possibilities of $a$.

If $a = 0$, then it's relatively easy. Given $\varepsilon > 0$, since $a_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n > N$ implies $|a_n - 0| = |a_n| = a_n < \varepsilon^2$, whence for all $n > N$, 
$|\sqrt{a_n} - \sqrt{a}| = |\sqrt{a_n}| < \sqrt{\varepsilon^2} = \varepsilon.$

If $a > 0$, choose $N$ based on $a_n \to a$ such that $|a_n - a| < \sqrt{a}\varepsilon$ for all $n > N$. Therefore for every $n > N$, we have
\begin{align*}
|\sqrt{a}_n - \sqrt{a}| = \frac{|a_n - a|}{\sqrt{a_n} + \sqrt{a}} <
\frac{\sqrt{a}\varepsilon}{\sqrt{a}} = \varepsilon.
\end{align*}
This completes the proof.

Comment: So I get the proof but are you not allowed to use a supremum? Like if we get $|a_n - a| < \epsilon (\sqrt{R} + \sqrt{a})$ , so then $$\frac{|a_n-a|}{|\sqrt{a_n} + \sqrt{a}|} < (\sqrt{R} + \sqrt{a})\frac{\epsilon}{(\sqrt{R} + \sqrt{a})} = \epsilon$$. Where R := sup($|a_n|$)

Comment: First, the inequality you wrote is wrong. Because $\sqrt{a_n} \leq \sqrt{R}$ implies the inequality in the opposite direction. Second, there is no need to bother supremum. To simplify the denominator, simply throw away the term $\sqrt{a_n}$ to get an upper bound.

Answer (score 0):

With $a\neq0$
$$|\sqrt{a_n}-\sqrt{a}|=\frac{|a_n-a|}{\sqrt{a_n}+\sqrt{a}}\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}|a_n-a|<\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\varepsilon$$
for $a=0$ let $\varepsilon<1$ so $a_n\to0$ shows $0\leq a_n<\varepsilon<1$ then $0\leq \sqrt{a_n}\leq \sqrt{\varepsilon}$ with arbitrary $\varepsilon<1$.